# Where can I find study materials?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, bigdata, self-study

Can anyone recommend me some material (books, blogs, youtube channels, ...) to study statistics, Machine Learning and in general Data Science topics?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deep Learning Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning) on Coursera: You can follow the lectures for free or apply for a scholarship if you can't afford it. Even though some content is a bit old, still a very extensive source from fundamental concepts of machine learning to advanced optimization concepts and additional courses on CNN's and Sequence models.

Also, there are several completely free courses on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/), from artificial intelligence, neural networks to more framework specific courses such as TensorFlow for deep learning, Machine Learning on Azure or AWS Deep Racer.

Also, [Sentdex](https://pythonprogramming.net/) has several tutorials on Data Analysis and Machine Learning. He has a nice style and usually goes through everything in detail.

[fast.ai](https://www.fast.ai/) is another comprehensive and completely free resource I can suggest.

And [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) (or [Keras](https://keras.io/)) also have very accessible resources and tutorials within their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

https://youtu.be/rfscVS0vtbw - Python basics

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZoTAELRMXVPBTrWtJkn3wWQxZkmTXGwe - Full Machine  learning tutorials

https://youtu.be/xxpc-HPKN28 - Statistics needed for Data Science

TBH this is all you need to get to an intermediate level.

PS: This only includes traditional machine learning. The op did not mention NLP/DL hence the reason.